# width:max-content,width:fit-content doesn't work in Edge

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a badge for a chatbot with dynamic width.Given below is the css for the same

```css
    #badge{
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        right: 66px;
        top: -24px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #d5d4d1;
        border: solid 1px #eae9e8;
        min-width:152px ;
        max-width:400px ;
        width:max-content;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #3f3d3a;
        visibility:inherit;
    }
```

The badge works as expected in Chrome and Firefox but it considers min-width property for Edge.I want the badge to dynamically change width based on text size.How do I achieve it in Edge?Is there any workaround?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please read this article carefully how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please reduce your css to the bare minimum needed to reproduce your issue. it will then be much easier to solve.

Comment: `max-content` is not supported by either IE or edge. https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content. It's possible that you might be able to achieve something similar with a different approach but you need to post a complete example if you want us to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
I fixed the issue by giving browser-specific(Edge) CSS properties.I specified  same set of properties but a slight change in width properties and also added white-space:nowrap to handle white spaces.

Given below is the CSS

@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    #badge{
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        right: 66px;
        top: -24px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #d5d4d1;
        border: solid 1px #eae9e8;
        min-width:232px ;
        max-width:400px ;
        white-space:nowrap;
        width:max-content;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #3f3d3a;
        visibility:inherit;
    }
}
```